# Reactjs MUIDataTable hide data

Tags: reactjs, react-native, mui-datatable

I have a table code that includes filter and search, but what I want is at first there should initially be no data appearing or display but when the user searches or uses a filter the result will appear in the table, how can I do such functionality or behavior?

the table I using is MUIDataTable, how can I hide the data in MUIDataTable ? if the user use the filter the data will appear or show?

this is my code

```
const Logs = () => {
  const classes = useStyles();
  const [state, setState] = useState([
    {
      startDate: new Date(),
      endDate: null,
      key: 'selection'
    }
  ]);
  
  const columns = [
    {
     name: "dateTime",
     label: "Date / Time",
     options: {
        filter: true,
        sort: false,
        display: 'true',
        filterType: 'custom',
        customFilterListOptions: {
          render: v => v.map(l => l.toUpperCase()),
          update: (filterList, filterPos, index) => {
            console.log('update');
            console.log(filterList, filterPos, index);
            filterList[index].splice(filterPos, 1);
            return filterList;
          }
        },
        filterOptions: {
          logic: (datetime, filters, row) => {
            if (filters.length) return !filters.includes(datetime);
            return false;
          },
          display: (filterList, onChange, index, column) => {
            const optionValues = ['Minneapolis', 'New York', 'Seattle'];
            return (
              <FormControl>
                <DateRange
                  editableDateInputs={true}
                  onChange={item => setState([item.selection])}
                  moveRangeOnFirstSelection={false}
                  ranges={state}
                />
              </FormControl>
            );
          }
        }
      }
    },
    {
     name: "user",
     label: "User",
     options: {
      filter: false,
      sort: false,
     }
    },
    {
     name: "appCode",
     label: "Application Code",
     options: {
        filter: true,
        display: 'true',
        filterType: 'custom',
        customFilterListOptions: {
          render: v => v.map(l => l.toUpperCase()),
          update: (filterList, filterPos, index) => {
            console.log('update');
            console.log(filterList, filterPos, index);
            filterList[index].splice(filterPos, 1);
            return filterList;
          }
        },
        filterOptions: {
          logic: (datetime, filters, row) => {
            if (filters.length) return !filters.includes(datetime);
            return false;
          },
          display: (filterList, onChange, index, column) => {
            const optionValues = ['Minneapolis', 'New York', 'Seattle'];
            return (
              <FormControl>
                <InputLabel htmlFor='select-multiple-chip'>
                  Application
                </InputLabel>
                <Select
                  multiple
                  value={filterList[index]}
                  renderValue={selected => selected.join(', ')}
                  onChange={event => {
                    filterList[index] = event.target.value;
                    onChange(filterList[index], index, column);
                  }}
                >
                  {optionValues.map(item => (
                    <MenuItem key={item} value={item}>
                      <Checkbox
                        color='primary'
                        checked={filterList[index].indexOf(item) > -1}
                      />
                      <ListItemText primary={item} />
                    </MenuItem>
                  ))}
                </Select>
              </FormControl>
            );
          }
        }
      }
    },
    {
     name: "module",
     label: "Module",
     options: {
        filter: true,
        display: 'true',
        filterType: 'custom',
        customFilterListOptions: {
          render: v => v.map(l => l.toUpperCase()),
          update: (filterList, filterPos, index) => {
            console.log('update');
            console.log(filterList, filterPos, index);
            filterList[index].splice(filterPos, 1);
            return filterList;
          }
        },
        filterOptions: {
          logic: (datetime, filters, row) => {
            if (filters.length) return !filters.includes(datetime);
            return false;
          },
          display: (filterList, onChange, index, column) => {
            const optionValues = ['Minneapolis', 'New York', 'Seattle'];
            return (
              <FormControl>
                <InputLabel htmlFor='select-multiple-chip'>
                  Module
                </InputLabel>
                <Select
                  multiple
                  value={filterList[index]}
                  renderValue={selected => selected.join(', ')}
                  onChange={event => {
                    filterList[index] = event.target.value;
                    onChange(filterList[index], index, column);
                  }}
                >
                  {optionValues.map(item => (
                    <MenuItem key={item} value={item}>
                      <Checkbox
                        color='primary'
                        checked={filterList[index].indexOf(item) > -1}
                      />
                      <ListItemText primary={item} />
                    </MenuItem>
                  ))}
                </Select>
              </FormControl>
            );
          }
        }
      }
    },
    {
     name: "transaction",
     label: "Transaction",
     options: {
        filter: true,
        display: 'true',
        filterType: 'custom',
        customFilterListOptions: {
          render: v => v.map(l => l.toUpperCase()),
          update: (filterList, filterPos, index) => {
            console.log('update');
            console.log(filterList, filterPos, index);
            filterList[index].splice(filterPos, 1);
            return filterList;
          }
        },
        filterOptions: {
          logic: (datetime, filters, row) => {
            if (filters.length) return !filters.includes(datetime);
            return false;
          },
          display: (filterList, onChange, index, column) => {
            const optionValues = ['Minneapolis', 'New York', 'Seattle'];
            return (
              <FormControl>
                <InputLabel htmlFor='select-multiple-chip'>
                  Transaction Type
                </InputLabel>
                <Select
                  multiple
                  value={filterList[index]}
                  renderValue={selected => selected.join(', ')}
                  onChange={event => {
                    filterList[index] = event.target.value;
                    onChange(filterList[index], index, column);
                  }}
                >
                  {optionValues.map(item => (
                    <MenuItem key={item} value={item}>
                      <Checkbox
                        color='primary'
                        checked={filterList[index].indexOf(item) > -1}
                      />
                      <ListItemText primary={item} />
                    </MenuItem>
                  ))}
                </Select>
              </FormControl>
            );
          }
        }
      }
    },
    {
     name: "table",
     label: "Table",
     options: {
      filter: false,
      sort: false,
     }
    },
    {
     name: "id",
     label: "ID",
     options: {
      filter: false,
      sort: false,
     }
    },
    {
     name: "record",
     label: "Record",
     options: {
      filter: false,
      sort: false,
     }
    },
   ];
    const data = [
      { 
        dateTime: "July 22, 2021 | 07:34:12 AM", 
        user: "TestUser", 
        appCode: "App", 
        module: "Module", 
        transaction: "Transaction", 
        table: "Table", 
        id: "ID", 
        record: "Record",
      },
    ];
   
   const options = {
     selectableRows: 'none',
     print: false, 
   };
   
  return (
    <>
      
      <CRow>
        <CCol>
          <MUIDataTable
            className="MuiGrid-grid-xs-6"
            title={"Audit Logs"}
            data={data}
            columns={columns}
            options={options}
          />
        </CCol>
      </CRow>
      
    </>
  )
}
```

Comment: What is the current behaviour ?

Comment: @TheRakeshPurohit the current behavior is the data is displayed